# Change (or add) id name using url parameters

Tags: javascript, url

I need to change or create a div from an url parameters

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

[www.example.com?change=newdiv](http://www.example.com?change=newdiv)

```
<div class="myclass" id="newdiv"></div>
```

Is it possible to do this with js?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it like that :) :

```js
      var url_string =   window.location.href; //window.location.href
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("change");
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
element[0].setAttribute("id",c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create new [URL](https://javascript.info/url) property using `https`, otherwise you will get a

> TypeError: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) is not a valid URL.

After that get the search parameter `change` and create a `div` where to set the `id`

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.example.com?change=newdiv');
const changeParamValue = url.searchParams.get("change");
console.log("param value: " + changeParamValue)

let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", changeParamValue);

console.log(newDiv)
```

Comment: This works only for the root url, i need it for all urls